# Determining amount of bytes read with recv

Tags: c, winsock, recv

I am having an issue with `recv`. I wrote a function that fills a structure with data, and the length (in bytes) of that data which is read from a socket.

For testing I am just printing the data to `stdout` byte by byte based on the total amount of bytes read by `recv`. For some reason the number of bytes being read seems to be correct sometimes and incorrect other times depending on what site I am querying. For example the following code works as intended on some sites:

```
data->data_sz = 0;
while((i = recv(sock, data->data + data->data_sz, CHUNKSIZE, 0)) > 0)
{
    data->data_sz += i;
    if(databff - data->data_sz < CHUNKSIZE)
    {
        databff *= 2;
        if(!(tmp = realloc(data->data, databff)))
        {
            free(data->data);
            (void) WSACleanup();
            return 0;
        }
        data->data = tmp;
    }
}
i = strsbstr(data->data, "\r\n\r\n") + 4;                   //i = the position of the first char after header info  
if(i >= 0)  
{
    data->data_sz = data->data_sz - i;                      //data->data_sz = number of bytes without header info
    memmove(data->data, data->data + i, data->data_sz);
    if(!(tmp = realloc(data->data, data->data_sz)))
    {
        free(data->data);
        (void)WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
        data->data = tmp;                       
    }
    else
    {
        free(data->data);
        (void) WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

To print the data to `stdout` I just use a for loop:

```
//t_html->data_sz points to my data->data_sz structure
//t_html->data points to my data->data structure
for(i = 0; i <= t_html->data_sz; i++) (void)fputc((int)t_html->data[i], stdout);
```

The above code works for some sites but fails on others (for example when querying `http://www.google.com` I expect the final characters to be `</html>` but I get `</html>l`).

Basically my problem is that `data->data_sz` (the amount of bytes received) is not being calculated correctly, which makes it impossible to correctly use gathered data. I am really at a loss of what to do right now.

EDIT:
here is the `strsbstr` function which is called in the above code:

```
int strsbstr(const char *str, const char *sbstr)
{
    char *sbstrlc;

    if(!(strcmp(str, sbstr))) return 0;
    if(!(sbstrlc = strstr(str, sbstr))) return -1;
    return (int) (sbstrlc - str);
}
```

Comment: Could you post a program that is compilable without adding the boilerplate and non-standard functions (such as `WSACleanup()`) you left out? That would make answering your question a lot easier.

Comment: WSACleanup() is a Winsock function. I'm not sure what you mean? I will update my post to show what `strsbstr` is doing though (if that's what you mean)?

Comment: I am sorry. I've only used Unix sockets so far and since you didn't present any includes I had no way to see it is a function from Windows. Still, it's a lot easier to debug your code if it is actually compilable (instead of being a fragment).

Comment: @FUZxxl: it's tagged "winsock."

Comment: Just a note: `i = strsbstr(data->data, "\r\n\r\n") + 4; if(i >= 0)` <- that will always be the case, in fact, `i >= 3`. You should check `i >= 4` or postpone the addition of 4 after the test.

Comment: Oh yeah I just noticed that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Keith Yeah. My fault. The comment about not providing a working example still holds though.

Comment: It's no problem I understand and appreciate your input, I will be sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `recv(sock, data->data + data->data_sz, CHUNKSIZE, 0)` is potentially a problem. Why? Because you may not have `CHUNKSIZE` room left in your buffer. You have `databff - data->data_sz` left, actually (assuming `data` is allocated to a size of `databff`). It all depends on the initial values of `databff` and `CHUNKSIZE`, which I can't see and figure I'd point this out just in case.
2. Data is not guaranteed to be NULL-character terminated. Your printing loop says `i <= t_html->data_sz;` which is wrong. It should be `i < t_html->data_sz;`. If you use `<=`, you're accessing one past your buffer, which is likely why you get a weird character sometimes, and sometimes not.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working now, I feel a bit silly that I missed that but I don't care at this point. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! The little details are the devil. I fixed my first point; I just realized I wrote the "actual size" wrong.